# Retrieve results by entering code number (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, search

I have a list of data,

Sheet1

```
Column A - Column B - Column C
GRE001     Great wall  NW3 5EP
BR003      Moon        SN2 2HT
NO004      Royal       NW6 1LN
```

I want to be able to type just the Code on sheet 2 for example GRE001 and have it display automatically the Name of the place and the postcode, will this be possible?
There will be a a lot more data, roughly about 1000 codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably accomplish this with a simple `VLOOKUP`.

Suppose you want to type the code in A1 on Sheet2, and have it show the place in B1 and the postal code in C1, then use the following formula in B1:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A:C,2,FALSE)
```

And in C1:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A:C,3,FALSE)
```

And if you want to make it clean in the event that the value doesn't exist in the lookup range, you can wrap in an `IFERROR` function like so:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A:C,2,FALSE),"")
```